# Tool/script for correcting order of xml elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using a custom tool for converting data from a proprietary format to Xml. 
However the generated Xml elements are in (seemingly) random order, so that the Xml file does not match the schema anymore.

Fixing the libraries of the tool is scheduled, but i need a quick fix for now (the files are big so fixing the xml manually would be very time-consuming). Is there any tool/script that can fix the order of Xml child elements according to a schema? It would be enough if it would go down the tree and on the way reorder the children of each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing a small C# program that reordered the elements. turned out it always were the same 4 types of elements that got their childrens' order randomized, so sorting those was not too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

1. use PHP's SimpleXML to read the XML to array,
2. use PHP's sorting functions to sort the array by element
3. export the sorted array to XML using PHP's fwrite / SimpleXML write functions